# when use teetree(TeeChart's one Component) build a imageshape,it's display with error

Tags: resize, teechart

when add a lot of picture node to the teetree control,and set text offset to 30,then scroll to the end,the last line display picture only.
how should i do?

this is the result of the error: [image: image of error]

```html
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:Integer;
imgBox:TImageShape;
  curLeft,curTop:Integer;       //绘制完成文档视图后当前左上角坐标
begin
  curLeft:=-100-15;
  curTop:=0;
  for i:=0 to 10 do
  begin
    imgBox := TImageShape.Create(Self);
    imgBox.Width := 100;
    imgBox.Height := 100;
    curLeft := curLeft + 100 + 15 * 2;
    if (curLeft + 100 + 15)>= Tree1.Width then
    begin
      curLeft := 15;
      curTop := curTop + 100 + 15 * 2;
    end;
    imgBox.Left := curLeft;
    imgBox.Top := curTop;
    imgBox.Font.Style:=[fsBold];
    imgBox.Font.Size:=16;
    imgBox.Text.VertAlign:=vtaBottom;
    imgBox.Text.VertOffset:=30;
    imgBox.Text.Add('Node'+inttostr(i));
    imgBox.ImageListIndex:=0;
    imgBox.Tree:=Tree1;
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added it to the public tracker [here](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1160) with a possible fix to be further investigated.